# Why do Youtube videos run fine then always give "audio renderer error" several days later?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

After a reboot, or following the actions listed below, everything involving audio runs fine. I can watch and hear Youtube videos, and run audio software w/o problems.

About a week or two of constant uptime and typically 9 to 14 hours of use, Youtube videos won't play, but instead display an "Audio renderer error". This happens always for all videos, until I take one of these actions:

- reboot (no thanks, I have several projects in progress up, with IDEs, video editors, etc)
- pulseaudio --kill; pulseaudio --start   but then all browser tabs that were playing audio (e.g. I always have defonic.com for ambient sounds running) go silent, and need to be reloaded. Audio software usually needs to restarted.
- Quitting Chromium and restarting it usually doesn't help, but maybe sometimes works - I haven't been keeping notes.
- Sometimes, closing pavucontrol lets chromium play video normally. I can even start playing a video then run pavucontrol and things are normal.
- Occasionally, after monkeying around with JACK Audio, softsynths, browser settings, running alsamixer, or doing nothing at all, it might magically start working, at least for a while.

Having worked with various kinds of software for years, my (unreliable) intuition is that PulseAudio has a limited number of something, channels, audio buffers, whatever, that get used up or aren't properly garbage collected. I'm not sure it's PulseAudio or ALSA, or a problem with Chromium but other audio software seems to be affected.

I'm running Arch, generally never more than six months out of date, last upgrade only a month ago.  The problem has been a bother since a few years ago. I don't remember specifically a first time.

Comment: Now I'm using Pipewire.  It replaces JACK, Pulse and ALSA.  Still getting these audio renderer errors from Chromium!  Makes Chromium look guilty.  Firefox always play audio w/o complaint (so far).

Comment: Found this to work when having the problem:  sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576   The number originally was somewhat over half a million.  Now YT videos play normally in Chromium.  For now...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by unplugging the earphone from my system. You can try this trick or check other solutions [here](https://droidtheory.com/fix-audio-renderer-error-please-restart-your-computer/)